# Where is the Houston anti-Food Sharing Ordinance?

Tags: texas, local-ordinance, houston

Accoring to [this article](https://www.houstonpublicmedia.org/articles/news/local/2023/02/28/444954/local-nonprofit-says-they-will-continue-to-feed-homeless-despite-city-of-houstons-warning-against-it/) about the anti-Food Sharing Ordinance in Houston,

> Mayor Anise Parker and city council passed an anti-food sharing ordinance that bans serving charitable meals on properties, public or private, without consent from the Mayor's office.

Where can I find this ordinance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ordinance is 2012-269 was signed by Mayor Parker in 2012 you can find it as

> [AN ORDINANCE AMENDING CHAPTER 20 OF THE CODE OF ORDINANCES, HOUSTON, TEXAS, RELATING TO FEEDING THOSE IN NEED; CONTAINING FINDINGS AND OTHER PROVISIONS RELATING TO THE FOREGOING SUBJECT; PROVIDING FOR SEVERABILITY; AND DECLARING AN EMERGENCY.](https://www.houstontx.gov/health/2012-269.pdf)

The section amended landed in [Chapter 20, Article V: Charitable Food Service.](https://library.municode.com/tx/houston/codes/code_of_ordinances?nodeId=COOR_CH20FODR_ARTVCHFOSE)